# The image doesnt show in the flatlist what am I missing here?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist, react-native-image-picker

I made an app in React Native where you can add a "player" and his/her "position" to a flatlist and after that, the user should be able to make a picture and it is supposed to show it in the flatlist along with the name and position. The problem is that it doesn't.

I tried to run it in different React installments, tried to resize it within the styles component, and even changed the source names. Nothing seems to work. Apparently, not even ChatGPT knows the answer to this :(.

What am I doing wrong or am I overlooking?
The code is below

ps. I'm just a student so don't be harsh on me...
also, the app just runs in an emulator

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { FlatList, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, Image, Button, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { launchCamera } from 'react-native-image-picker';

const App = () => {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [position, setPosition] = useState('');
  const [image, setImage ] = useState(null);
  
  const addPlayer = () => {
    setPlayers([...players, { name,position, image: null }]);
    setName('');
    setPosition('');
    setImage(null)
  };

  const openCamera = () => {
    let options = {
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images',
      },
    };
    launchCamera(options, (res) => {
      setImage(res);
      console.log('response = ', res.assets[0].uri);

    });
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        value={name}
        onChangeText={setName}
        placeholder="Enter player name"
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        value={position}
        onChangeText={setPosition}
        placeholder="Enter position"
      />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={addPlayer} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={{ color: '#fff' }}>Add Player</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <FlatList
  data={players}
  renderItem={({item}) => (
    <View style={styles.playerContainer}>
      {item.image && item.image.uri && (
        <Image
          source={{ uri: item.image.uri }}
          style={{width:60, height:60,borderRadius:30, backgroundColor: black}}
        />
      )}
      <View style={{alignItems:"center",flex:1}}>
        <Text style={{fontWeight:"bold"}}>{item.name}</Text>
        <Text>{item.position}</Text>
      </View>

      <Button
        title="Take Picture"
        onPress={(openCamera)}
      />
    </View>
  )}
  keyExtractor={item => item.name}
      />
</View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 16,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    padding: 12,
  },
  playerContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginBottom: 16,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  playerImage: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    borderRadius: 25,
  
  },
  playerName: {
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

playerContainer:{
height:70,
width:70,
flexDirection: 'row',
marginBottom: 16,
alignItems: 'center',
}

or wrap your image inside another view and give that view style with same height and width that you gave in image:

Comment: <View style={{height:60, width:60}}>
        <Image
          source={{ uri: item.image.uri }}
          style={{width:60, height:60,borderRadius:30, backgroundColor: black}}
        />
</View>